# Power BI visual is not working in workspace or powerapp. What may the fix be?

Tags: python, error-handling, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88bzB.png)

The Power BI visual worked just fine yesterday and the previous weeks. However, today it does not for me and several other users. The Power BI visual does work on my Power BI desktop. I tried to refresh the server, that did not resolve the problem. Where can I look to troubleshoot?

The visual does use some Python script, but it works on my desktop.

```
Can't display this visual
Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later.
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support,
please provide these details.
Hide details
Error CodeMissingJobResult
Activity ID75c098ff-a696-49a0-8e37-929014e9a4ca
Correlation ID330c3db6-493f-74e6-4305-eaaf5ef8bd52
Request ID3fbfb250-c16c-81dc-c297-8c5704703897
Cluster URIhttps://wabi-us-north-central-d-primary redirect.analysis.windows.net/
```

Comment: Please post the error message, not its screenshot

Comment: Jan, I have updated the question with the error message. Thank you!